# Tab key sending twice when using Custom Control with Override ProcessCmdKey

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code to Override the **ProcessCmdKey**.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Enter))
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

All works fine except for one thing. I am using a custom control, a custom **textbox** with auto suggest list (like **combobox** style). When I'm typing on the custom control and pressing pressing enter key to select the item, the item is correctly selected but it send tab twice. It will focus on the 2nd **textbox** instead of focusing on the 1st **textbox**. I already checked the tab index and it's properly numbered.

Comment: I think you need to return `true` after sending the `tab`

Comment: When I put return true after the sendkeys, it will go/tab to the next textbox but did not select the item I selected.

Comment: Check the values of the `TabIndex` properties of your controls.

Comment: As i mentioned above, TabIndex numbering is okay.